# Using PCA to obtain the eigenfaces

Tags: matlab, pca

I have 10 face images and each image have 56x46 pixel.
I am trying to obtain the eigenface using PCA, but there is some problems.

Here is my matlab code

```
function a01_v2()
load facedata.mat;

S=[];
 mean=zeros(56,46,'double');
for i=1:1:10
    S=[S,facedata{1,i}];
    mean=mean+double(facedata{1,i});
end
mean=mean/10;


%figure,imshow(S);
S=reshape(S,10,2576);

S=double(S);

figure,imshow(uint8(mean));
c=cov(S);
[v,d]=eigs(c,9);
figure,imshow(uint8(reshape((v(:,1)),56,46)));


end
```

Comment: Which problems, exactly?

Comment: cov function are not support uint8,i convert it to double.
but i don't know how to reconstruct the eigenfaces